# Open website in Outlook's internal browser via VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to open a given webpage via VBA.  I can do this using:

```
Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
browser.Navigate ("http://google.com")
```

but this opens an instance of IE.  I'd like to open it in Outlooks integrated browser window.

I'd presume this is fairly easy, but I'm not familiar with VBA and googling has not turned up anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of out are you using ? older version did have a browse toolbar.

and you can use the technique above to hook the commandbars you can do this in VBA marco as well, you dont actualy need a addin.

You can also do it via the **Folder Home Page Feature** as folders can show a web page instead of the normal folder contents. (*right click propteries > home page tab*)

You can set this via the OOM:

Set the  [Folder.WebViewURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176546.aspx) Property to your URL and set the [Folder.WebViewOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176545.aspx) Property to True

You can do this on th currently selected folder from the Active Explorer but remember to set it back afterward.

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2007.  I was completely unaware of the option to use a webpage as the default view for a folder!  Thanks