# How to programmatically open an Outlook Shortcut

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, add-in

I'm wondering if there is a way of programmatically opening an Outlook Shortcut from my addin.

I've created the shortcut as follows

```
Sub AddShortcut()
    Dim myOlBar As Outlook.OutlookBarPane
    Dim myolGroup As Outlook.OutlookBarGroup
    Dim myOlShortcuts As Outlook.OutlookBarShortcuts

    myOlBar = Application.ActiveExplorer.panes.Item("OutlookBar")
    myolGroup = myOlBar.Contents.Groups.Item(1)
    myOlShortcuts = myolGroup.Shortcuts
    myOlShortcuts.Add("http://microsoft.com/", _
    "MSHomepage", 1)
End Sub
```

I'm guessing I need to use `InvokeMember` in some way

```
myOlShortcuts("MSHomepage").GetType().InvokeMember(..)
```

But when I use `GetType().GetMethods()` I can't see any `Click` members or something similar. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [trigger the Outlook integrated web browser](http://www.outlookcode.com/d/tips/formhyperlink.htm), you should grab the [`OutlookBarShortcut.Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868031.aspx). If the **Target** is of type `string`, then use the following (*substituting your Target for the address Text*)...

```cs
Office.CommandBarComboBox address = (Office.CommandBarComboBox)Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.FindControl(26, 1740);
address.Text = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

otherwise the type is `Folder` and you should assign [`Explorer.CurrentFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866719). The only downside with this approach is that [`CommandBars` have been deprecated with Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865324.aspx) and this solution likely won't work in the next version of Office.

Another alternative is to use [Web Folder behavior as discussed in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233456/175679). You could create a hidden `Folder` used just for the purposes of navigation.