# Is there a way to programmatically recall e-mails via Outlook/Exchange?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, message

Does anyone know if this is possible? I can't see to find much info about doing so other than to even recall a message both sender & receiver must be using Exchange and the e-mail has to be unread on the receiver's end. There's rarely a case where this would need to be done but even so it would be useful to know.

**Edit**

- Outlook 2010 is the version I am using.

Comment: A place to start looking would be the Outlook MAPI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765775.aspx I confess I've never used it but if it is anything like the excel or office COM APIs you should be able to perform any task that you can normally do in the regular user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FindControl ID for "Recall This Message" is `2511`, so you could use some code like this:

```
Sub SendRecall()

  Dim obj As Object
  Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

  ' get selected item
  Set obj = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

  If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
    Set msg = obj
    Set insp = msg.GetInspector
    ' execute the command button for "Recall this message"
    With insp
      .Display
      .CommandBars.FindControl(, 2511).Execute
      .Close olDiscard
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

**Works in Outlook 2003, you did not post your version so I'm not sure if this solution will work for you.**

Comment: I'm in Outlook 2010, but none the less this is helpful, thanks!

Comment: I believe the CommandBars Object [has been deprecated in Outlook 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004739/190829).

Comment: I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864119) is the new version of what was depreciated.