# Opening an Outlook shorcut

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

[image]!

It turns out I was attempting to do this almost 2 years ago in [How to programmatically open an Outlook Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996394/how-to-programmatically-open-an-outlook-shortcut) and I decided it wasn't needed at the time. So I'm writing for Outlook 2010/13 and I need to create a shortcut (making this explicitly clear what I mean via attached image as some documentation refers to context menu shortcuts) and I then need to open that shortcut using the outlook integrated web browser from a button click on the explorer ribbon.

One way of doing something similar is to create a sub folder in say the inbox and set its webviewurl and on my button click I switch the current folder to be the subfolder. This is something I've done and it works quite nicely. But I don't want a folder, I want to do this via a proper shortcut. It looks better and nobody wonders what the folder is for.

Can anyone help me? Sorry for the length of post